# Text field with expression not working in HTML preview

Tags: jasper-reports

I have this condition expression in a text field

```
$F{StatusId}.toString().equals('6') ? $F{Cost}: null
```

The problem is it will return empty in HTML but can work correctly in the others preview format.

I've tried several condition before like code below but still it will return empty in HTML preview.

```
$F{StatusId} == 6 ? $F{Cost}: null
$F{StatusId}.intValue() == 6 ? $F{Cost}: null
```

Anybody had the same issues before?

- JasperReport 6.2.2
- JasperReports Server 6.2.1

Comment: Seems strange. Have you tried printing the field on the report for debugging? If it is an `int`, the second line should be enough (no need to convert to String or intValue()).

Comment: It's working already but I still haven't get the problem.

Comment: Ok, *have you tried printing the field*?